# Credit Card swiping from mobile devices for event registrations and contributions

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, payment-processor

Is there a solution to allow credit card swiping from mobile devices for event and contribution pages?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is! iATS Payments has an encrypted USB card reader that works with its CiviCRM iATS extension as well as a mobile phone card reader that works with their App.

For the mobile option: we're actively working on code required to be pushing them into your CiviCRM as well.

Organizations use it during checkout at fundraising events and in the office to swipe card / walk-ins.

Comment: The above answer says "Yes there is!" but then says "we're actively working on code" for the mobile option. I interpret that to mean, "no there isn't, unless you have a laptop with an internet connection and USB port." I have the same question as we are setting up CiviCRM for the first time and really need to be able to get people to use a phone or tablet at live gatherings for contribution and event transactions. Our organization currently uses Square, but that requires an extra, cumbersome import step to correctly update the CiviCRM DB. Square payment processor w/mobile swipe needed.